# Draw a tail like swift key keyboard iOS

Tags: ios, drawing, uigraphicscontext

I want to make custom keyboard . i done all the features , but swipe feature can't implement in my app. When I swipe on keyboard the letters type correctly but the line (draw) can't draw perfectly & i can't remove the old path of points.so please help.I want this type of swipe.

[image]

I write this code

```
- (void)touchesBegan: (NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event {
CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
myPath=nil;
[_myPathArray removeAllObjects];

myPath=[[UIBezierPath alloc]init];
myPath.lineCapStyle=kCGLineCapRound;
myPath.lineWidth=5.0;

_brushPattern=[UIColor redColor];

_myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

UITouch *mytouch=[[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
[myPath moveToPoint:[mytouch locationInView:self]];}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent: (UIEvent *)event {
CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
[myPath addLineToPoint:location];
shapeLayer.path = myPath.CGPath;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = _brushPattern.CGColor;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0;
shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
[self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
[self setNeedsDisplay];}
```

This code gives this result. But i want to remove path after some path draw..like **swype keyboard**.
[image]

Comment: Show at least the code where you draw, where you try to remove the old path, etc.

Comment: Where do you remove the `CALayer` that you added?

Comment: ya I remove CAShapeLayer in touchesEnded Method..This removes whole path ,but i want to remove only first point of the path.

Comment: @Milanpatel did you find out the solution?

Comment: no I don't found any solution for this...If you know then please suggest me.Thanks